# What is the location of firefox extension files on Mac OSx?

Tags: firefox-addon, osx-snow-leopard, selenium-ide

I am having an issue with Selenium IDE extension. I get following error for typeKeys command

(ff22, Selenium IDE 2.1.0)

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js, lineNumber -> 340, columnNumber -> 8
```

I want to know the location of : chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js

the extension directory looks sth like this:

[image]

Neither of the folder has the desired file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions are packaged. That file is inside one of those .xpi files (highligh-elements_selenium-ide@Samit.badle.xpi?).

You can change the .xpi extension to .zip and extract the files and you should be able to see that file.

Answer (score 1):

Like Filipe mentioned, the htmlutils.js is packaged inside the .xpi file, specifically the {a6fd85ed-e919-4a43-a5af-8da18bda539f}.xpi, which is the Selenium IDE addon for Firefox. You can rename it to .zip and extract it.

There is a simpler way if you just want to take a look at htmlutils.js or a similar file. You can simply put its chrome url "chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js" in the url bar in Firefox and press the Enter key. Firefox will show it to you without having to find out where it is or extracting it.

Cheers,
Samit Badle

Selenium IDE Maintainer. Twitter: @samitbadle
Blog: http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/

Comment: thanks Samit, mainly I needed this info to debug the script , as now the new version is released and most of the bugs seems to be fixed.But this info is still useful in future :)